# qt: qlayout do not correctly add widget

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want do dynamically change the layout in Qt. For example, I want to change the `QHBoxLayout` to `QVBoxLayout` through a button. My test code is:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class SubWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lay = QHBoxLayout()
        self.label1 = QLabel('left')
        self.label2 = QLabel('right')
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

    def change(self):

        self.lay.removeWidget(self.label1)
        self.lay.removeWidget(self.label2)

        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label1)

class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lay = QVBoxLayout()

        self.btn = QPushButton('change layout')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btnClick)

        self.subWidget = SubWidget()

        lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        lay.addWidget(self.subWidget)
        self.setLayout(lay)

    def btnClick(self, check=False):
        self.subWidget.change()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Widget()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

The code output GUI is:

[image]

And I hope it change to the following picture after click `change layout` button:

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the solution is

1. Make sure old layout is deleted, included both python wrapping reference and core Qt object, that's for `deleteLater()` is used.
2. Make sure new layout is assigned strictly after old was deleted, that's for need to use `destroyed()-switchlayout()` signal-slot chain.

I reproduced example with PySide6 (don't forget to switch on your version of PyQt or PySide package):

```py
# from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class SubWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label1 = QLabel('left')
        self.label2 = QLabel('right')
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

    def change(self):
        self.lay.removeWidget(self.label1)
        self.lay.removeWidget(self.label2)
        self.lay.deleteLater()
        self.lay.destroyed.connect(self.switchlayout)

    def switchlayout(self):
        # print("***destroyed")
        self.lay = QHBoxLayout()
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label2)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.label1)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.adjustSize()        

class Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lay = QVBoxLayout()

        self.btn = QPushButton('change layout')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btnClick)

        self.subWidget = SubWidget()

        lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        lay.addWidget(self.subWidget)
        self.setLayout(lay)

    def btnClick(self, check=False):
        self.subWidget.change()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Widget()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: It would be much simpler in this particular case to just [change the layout direction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#setDirection) from `LeftToRight` to `BottomToTop`.

Comment: @ekhumoro indeed